# Render a sub route in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Before I begin I have been on the https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start to grasp the idea of how the react router works. I have created a simple 3 page site in react and I want to create a list which will allow me to show some nested components. Whilst the examples on reacttraining.com nicely work on in a singles js file. I have my site split over 3 js files:

**APP.JS**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';


import {Home} from './Home';
import {User} from './User';
import {Artwork} from './artwork'
import {Header} from './header';



class App extends Component {



render(){
    return (

        <Router>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <Header />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/home" exact component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/user" component={User}/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>

    );
 }


}

export default App;
```

**USER.JS  Edited on 28/03/2017**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Artwork} from './artwork';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


export class User extends Component {


render() {
    return (


    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4">
            <h3>The User Page</h3>
            <p>User ID:</p>
            <li><Link to="/user/artwork">Artwork</Link></li>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8">
            <Route path="/user/artwork" component={Artwork}/>
        </div>

    </div>

    );
   }
}

export default User;
```

**ARTWORK.JS**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Art extends Component {


render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Art</h3>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Art;
```

The issue that I am having is that whilst i can navigate through to my top level menu items (Home and User) I can not access the artwork component on the the user page. when the artwork button is pressed my user component is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at the basic example on [react-training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), you'll notice that the "child" `Route` in the Topics component has `${match.url}/:topicId` as the path:

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
```

This is basically turning it into `topics/:topicId` which is needed because the top most component wouldn't know what to do with just `:topicId`.

Likewise, in your situation, your `App.js` doesn't know what to do with `/artwork` so it doesn't render anything. If you change your `Route` path and `Link` to in `User.js` to `/user/artwork` it should start working as desired.

To make your User component more composable/reusable, you'd want to do the same thing as react training and use the passed in `match.url` on the props.

Comment: Hi @James Ganong thank you for the reply, I did a quick edit to my code and implemented what you suggested. by changing the 'Route' path and Link in User.js to /user/artwork and unfortunately it did not work. Also I notice that the example on [react-training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) uses a functional approach rather than ES6 classes so would not the implementation be slightly different? tnxs again

Comment: I think the main issue may be that your Artwork.js class is named `Art`. Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ganong/pen/OpBzZY?editors=0010) that basically sets up what you're trying to do. It has to do with the way you're importing/exporting the classes. `import {Artwork} from './Artwork';` is taking the named export instead of the export default, and there is no Artwork exported. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi @James Ganong many tnxs for your time and codepen, you were and are correct. I was importing incorrectly my component, something I need to be mindful of in the future. I will take a close look into at `match.url` to make more composable/reusuable components tnxs again.

Comment: My pleasure - glad you got it sorted.